# return reordered version of array b based on reordered version of a

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays `a` and `b` like this:

```
const a = [1,2,3,4]
const b = ['1','2','3','4'] // could be 'a','b','c','d'

const reordered_a = [4,1,3,2] // based on this reordering 

function reorder_b() {
    // should return ['4','1','3','2']
}
```

How can I return reordered version of `b` based on reordered positions in `reordered_a`?

Comment: `[...b].sort(mySortingFunction)` using [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: There are several ways to approach this. What have you tried?

Comment: Close voters please at least read the question you wanna close one time and mark is as duplicate ... same title of questions doesn't mean it's duplicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object with the indices for the values and map the pattern with the values of the indices.

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const b = ['1', '2', '3', '4'] // could be 'a','b','c','d'

const reordered_a = [4, 1, 3, 2] // based on this reordering 

function reorder_b() {
   const references = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(a).map(a => a.reverse()));
   return reordered_a.map(k => b[references[k]]);
}

console.log(reorder_b()); // 4 1 3 2
```

Comment: As always Nina...

Answer (score -1):

What you got to do is first use every pair of elements `el1` and `el2` and convert them to numbers. Then once they're converted, make sure that the latter is bigger than the latter by checking their difference  :

```js
return b.sort((el1,el2)=>Number(el2)-Number(el1))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since it doesn't sort according to array `a`?

Comment: const b = ['1','2','3','4'] // could be 'a','b','c','d'

Comment: Oh you mean for any particular order, not sorted specifically? But if we're using  'a','b','c','d', should it return 'd','c','b','a'?

Comment: should return d a c b...

Comment: I used numbers to make it easer to understand